# Modally presenting Storyboard in Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, uistoryboard, segue

I have a `UIStoryboard` that consists of 4 to 5 `ViewControllers`. These `ViewControllers` are connected with each other through push segue. This story board is not embedded inside `NavigationController`.

Now i have to use this `UIStoryboard` on two different scenario in my application.

1. This `UIStoryboard` is pushed inside a `ViewController` which is already inside a `NavigationController` so i can simply do like this.

   UIStoryboard *myStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"myStoryboard" bundle:nil];
       UIViewController *vc = (UIViewController *)[myStoryboard instantiateInitialViewController];
       [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];

This works perfectly fine as we are pushing the `UIStoryboard` inside a `NavigationController` so for further navigation `UIStoryboard's` `ViewControllers` can use the `NavigationController` in which the story board is pushed.

- The second scenario is that is have to modally present this `UIStoryBoard` from a viewController which i can do like.

  UIStoryboard *myStoryBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"myStoryBoard" bundle:nil];
              UIViewController *vc = [myStoryBoard instantiateInitialViewController];

  [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:^{

  ```
          }];
  ```

It is presented successfully but now as the `UIStoryboard` is not in any `NavigationController` when i do a push Seque from first `ViewController` to second `ViewController` inside the `UIStoryboard` it crashes (which it should) saying

```
Could not find a navigation controller for segue.  Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.'
```

Can some body tell how i can solve this problem or how i can programmatically embed or remove the `UIStoryboard` inside the `NavigationController`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will not work because you are triggering the root segue from a controller which is push modally and not contained in a navigation controller.

You probably want to swap your hierarchy around so that the main view is in the nav controller which is the window root view controller and the other view controller is push modally.

You actually have to set your UIViewController as the root controller of a UINavigationController (or pushed through from a view controller wia navcontroller). To do that

1. Drag a new navigation controller into your storyboard before view controller
2. Right click on the navgiation controller, and connect the "Root View Controller" property to your existing view controller.
3. Move the entry point arrow from your view controller to the root view controller

Hope this will help.